# How to back check classification using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression, naivebayes

I am running two different classification algorithms on my data logistic regression and naive bayes but it is giving me same accuracy even if I change the training and testing data ratio. Following is the code I am using

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB


df = pd.read_csv('Speed Dating.csv', encoding = 'latin-1')

X = pd.DataFrame()
X['d_age'] = df ['d_age']
X['match'] = df ['match']
X['importance_same_religion'] = df ['importance_same_religion']
X['importance_same_race'] = df ['importance_same_race']
X['diff_partner_rating'] = df ['diff_partner_rating']

# Drop NAs
X = X.dropna(axis=0)
# Categorical variable Match [Yes, No]
y = X['match']
# Drop y from X
X = X.drop(['match'], axis=1)

# Transformation
scalar = StandardScaler()
X = scalar.fit_transform(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Logistic Regression
model = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Accuracy Score with Logistic Regression: ', accuracy_score(y_test, model.predict(X_test)))

#Naive Bayes
model_2 = GaussianNB()
model_2.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Accuracy Score with Naive Bayes: ', accuracy_score(y_test, model_2.predict(X_test)))
print(model_2.predict(X_test))
```

Is it possible that every time the accuracy is same ?

Comment: Is it because of your input, `X` being a `numpy array` and target, `y` a `pandas series` object while calling `train_test_split` mismatch in types causing no impact on the model's accuracy? You can cast `y` as an array using `y.values` and check indeed if that's the issue.

Comment: That was one issue but I have solved it by converting everything into a dataframe but still I am getting the similar accuracy. In fact I have found that the accuracy for example is 80% because 80% of the test data contains zeros so actually model is not working at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is common phenomena occurring if the class frequencies are unbalanced, e.g. nearly all samples belong to one class. For examples if 80% of your samples belong to class "No", then classifier will often tend to predict "No" because such a trivial prediction reaches the highest overall accuracy on your train set.

In general, when evaluating the performance of a binary classifier, you should not only look at the overall accuracy. You have to consider other metrics such as the ROC Curve, class accuracies, f1 scores and so on.

In your case you can use sklearns [classification report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) to get a better feeling what your classifier is actually learning:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

print(classification_report(y_test, model_1.predict(X_test)))
print(classification_report(y_test, model_2.predict(X_test)))
```

It will print the precision, recall and accuracy for every class.

There are three options on how to reach a better classification accuracy on your class "Yes"

- use sample weights, you can increase the importance of the samples of the "Yes" class thus forcing the classifier to predict "Yes" more often
- downsample the "No" class in the original X to reach more balanced class frequencies
- upsample the "Yes" class in the original X to reach more balanced class frequencies